# VSCodeで ::ありのクラスで、素直にジャンプしてほしい

Tags: ruby, vscode

例えば下記のようなコードがあったとします。

```
module Hoge
  class Foo
  end
end

module Baz
  class Foo
  end
end


class Fuga < Hoge::Foo
end
```

上記の `class Fuga < Hoge::Foo` の `Foo` の上でコマンドクリックすると、下記のHogeの中のFooに飛んでほしいのですが、関係ないファイルの一覧が表示されて、自分で選ばなければなりません。

```
module Hoge
  class Foo
  end
end
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

今回のようなシンプルなコードだと、よいですが、未知のコードを読んでいるときは、選択が苦痛です。

なにかよい方法はありませんか？